# NSMutableArray is empty when i call it

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nsmutablearray

When i try to call a NSMutableArray from a diffirent class its empty why?

CLASS A

```
.h
@interface Dashboard : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *tablearrayCREDITS;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *tablearrayCREDITS;

.m
@synthesize tablearrayCREDITS;
```

And im filling it with data from a JSON array.This all works as it should be..

CLASS B

```
.h
    #import "Dashboard.h"

    @interface CreditsAndDebits : UIViewController {


    //nothing needed here..

}

.m

@implementation CreditsAndDebits
@synthesize selectedIndexPath;
    NSMutableArray *thearray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    Dashboard *db = [[Dashboard alloc]init];
    thearray = db.tablearrayCREDITS;
}
```

//When i debug it and set a breakpoint on where i allocate the Dashboard.. the tablearrayCREDITS says objects 0??, i dont get it? why is it going empty when im calling it?

Comment: You haven't shown any code where you assign a mutable array to tablearrayCREDITS, nor any code where you add items to that array.

Comment: Adding objects in the dashboard view goes correctly.. just before when i open the view of Class B: Nslog result :  Count of ThatArray: 278

Comment: The db that you're using in B's -viewDidLoad is a new object, not the same Dashboard instance to which you previously added 278 objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    Dashboard *db = [[Dashboard alloc]initWithNibName:@"Dashboard" bundle:nil...........];


    db.tablearrayCREDITS=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [db.tablearrayCREDITS addObject:@"madhu"];

    thearray = db.tablearrayCREDITS;


//here nslog them
}

//you have to create Dashboard object not mutable array
```

Comment: How can i init a nib to a NSMutablearray..? the inteligence wont show initwithnibname.

Comment: I've formatted the code in the answer as code, but unfortunately, as written, it leaks.

Comment: It still doesn't saves the objects in it.. it keeps going to 0 when i call it.

Comment: nslog this db.tablearrayCREDITS;

Comment: NSlog result as code above shows : Dynacloud-Finance[6962:7107] Checking it.. (
    madhu
)

Answer (score 0):

The array you call is empty because it is probably **not initialized** yet. You need to initialize that view before you call it.  You can do this with the `init` method for that view.

Or you can initialize that array when the app is launched. You can do this in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the AppDelegate.